# Unable to connect to database via WCF service

Tags: wcf, kerberos

I am unable to connect to database via IIS hosted WCF service but can connect to the same database via console application using the same code.

I can connect to other database(s) in the same server via WCF service. The WCF service is running under my account.

We are using Kerberos authentication for database connection.

Any ideas what could be the problem ?

Is there any settings on the database which can enable connection to db via WCF service.

Comment: What is the exact exception you get? include inner exceptions as well and the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

When the application hosted in IIS connects to the Database, the windows integrated security is no longer valid since the IIS has a security feature called Application pool identity.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

[image]
You either change the application pool identity to the practical account that can connect the database or switch to SQL server authentication.
Using SQL Server authentication is wise and most possible, we just Username/password to connect your database. Like below.

> data source=10.157.18.36\SQLExpress;initial catalog=TestStore;user
>   id=sa;password=123456;

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.